# Как взорвать гранату через определенное время после броска в steamvr unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, steam, vr

В игре steamer unity есть граната, к которой прикреплен сценарий гранаты. Взаимодействующий компонент событий наведения также прикреплен к grenade, который вызывает функцию Explode() из файла Grenadde. Взрыв происходит сразу после освобождения предмета из рук. Необходимо реализовать взрыв гранаты, например, за 5 секунд`

```
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Valve.VR.InteractionSystem;


public class Grenadde : MonoBehaviour
{

    InteractableHoverEvents interactableHoverEvents;
    public float delay = 3f;
    public float radius = 50f;
    public float force = 700f;
 
    public GameObject explosionEffect;
   
    float countdown;
    bool hasExploded = false;
    private Interactable interactable;
    public bool isGrabbed=false;
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        countdown = delay;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        if(interactable = null)
        {
        countdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (countdown <= 0f && !hasExploded )
        {
           Explode();
           hasExploded = true;
           Debug.Log("Lolo");
        } }
    }

    
    public void Explode()
    {
        /*countdown = delay;
        countdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (countdown <= 0f && !hasExploded)
        {*/
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Instantiate(explosionEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Collider[] overlappedColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

          for (int i=0; i < overlappedColliders.Length; i++) {

            Rigidbody rigidbody  = overlappedColliders[i].attachedRigidbody;
             if (rigidbody) {
                 
               rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(force, transform.position, radius);
               Grenadded grenadded = rigidbody.GetComponent<Grenadded>();
        
                  if(grenadded){
                    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, rigidbody.position) < radius);
                    grenadded.Hp -= 100;
                    grenadded.Explode();
                  }
           }   
        } 

       /*Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

       foreach (Collider nearbyObject in colliders)
       {
          Rigidbody rb = nearbyObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
          if (rb != null)
          {
             rb.AddExplosionForce(force, transform.position, radius);
          }
       }*/

        
        
    }
    //}
     
    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При бросании гранаты можно запускать корутину с таймером, после чего вызывать метод взрыва.

Comment: Чеку отдёргивать не пробовал?

Answer (score 1):

Не вникал, что именно происходит в методе Explode(), но если нужно, что бы он выполнился с отсрочкой по времени, то вот код:

```
public void Explode()
{
    StartCoroutine(ExplodeWithTimer(5f));
}

public IEnumerator ExplodeWithTimer(float seconds)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);

    Destroy(gameObject);
    Instantiate(explosionEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Collider[] overlappedColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

    for (int i = 0; i < overlappedColliders.Length; i++)
    {

        Rigidbody rigidbody = overlappedColliders[i].attachedRigidbody;
        if (rigidbody)
        {

            rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(force, transform.position, radius);
            Grenadded grenadded = rigidbody.GetComponent<Grenadded>();

            if (grenadded)
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, rigidbody.position) < radius) ;
                grenadded.Hp -= 100;
                grenadded.Explode();
            }
        }
    }
}
```